# Calculate property with request data in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have class Feedback in models in my django project. It has some charField, IntegerField.. and also custom property.

Hovewer what I need is to have a property calculated from input value (from request query params from URL). It means that it is calculated by each request.

My goal is to provide this calculated property with all attributes and other properties of object feedback on list view via Rest Framework.

```
class Company(CalculatedSummaryModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    @property
    def feedbacks(self):
        return Feedback.objects.all()

    def get_lookback_period(self, params):
        try:
            period = int(params['days'])
        except:
            period = 0
        return period
    
    
class CompanyView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        lookback_period = instance.get_lookback_period(request.query_params)
        setattr(instance, 'lookback_period', lookback_period)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    
class CompanySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    model = Company
    departments = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Department.objects.all(),view_name="department-detail")
    period = serializers.CharField(source='get_lookback_period')

    class Meta(BasicSerializer.Meta):
        model = Company
        fields = ['url', 'name','feedbacks', 'departments', 'period']
```

What I need is to create field as period and then filter from all feedbacks based on this period and do some other calculations.
The lookback period is not static, but dynamic from url (query parameters). So how can I add value from model method into serializer and display it in get request in API?
URL example : ..company?lookback_period=5

[image]

Thx for your advice.

Comment: Can you add more code to better explain?

Comment: Properties do not accept arguments, you need a method for this

Comment: Why don't you simply add a method to your model. @property getters don't accept any values so your only option is to already have the value in the model instance. Since your input parameters vary by each request I don't think property is the way to go. Use a method.

Comment: If you plan to filter based on this calculated value, or if the calculation is 'expensive' and static, it may be worth saving it to a field in the model (override save() is one way)

Comment: @vinkomlacic and others but it is possible to provide this method which returns filtered feedbacks in list-view in API with other property like name, all feedbacks .. for each team?

Comment: The method can take any parameter you want, I think you can make it work like that. Just call it from the view method and pass whatever GET parameters you think are relevant. In the end, calculated property is nothing more than a method, just a bit hidden.

Comment: I added my code in description for better understanding of the problem.